# Basic PayPal express checkout

Tags: paypal, opencart

I have a store running opencart which already has a fully functional shopping cart running, it is just requesting an API and authentication details.

So, how can I simply setup a API and be done with it, do i need to setup a sandbox account etc.

I just want a very simple setup for accepting payments via paypal and credit cards in NZ

Ive checked all the online guides and they are all for older layouts/designs of paypal.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing You need to is to install and enable (both if not yet done) the PayPal standard (or Paypal Express checkout) payment options in OpenCart administration - as far as I understand Your problem clearly.

Go to administration Extensions -> Payments and here scroll to find the PayPal payment options (should be three by default: PayPal Standard, PayPal Website Payment Pro and PayPal Website Payment Pro UK) - PayPal Standard should be Your bet. If `Install` action is available on the right, click on it and afterwards click on `Edit` action. Insert Your account information, select `Enabled` status and Your are done.

Now users should be able to select this payment option and after confirming the order they should be redirected to PayPal to pay for their orders.